# Security concerns

Tags: security

I'm not very versed in WiFi technology and jargon, so please keep this simple. Suppose you have an item that you don't want to give access to your main WiFi network, for security reasons. Suppose further that the device, per the manufacturer, will not work with a guest network. One option might be to get another router, connect it by ethernet to your internet provider's modem and create a separate network just for the item.

A couple of questions:

o How would that compare to using a guest network?

o Could the device or app get access to your main WiFi network, assuming some devious software?

Thanks.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The manufacturer probably means that it has to be on the same network as your phone. And many "guest" networks dont allow devices to talk with each other. If yours has a setting to allow that, you maybe ok with having the device and the phone both on the guest network. Otherwise, you could have the separate router like you suggested (with its own DHCP). But you'll probably have to then have your phone on that network too. And if you have a smart tv that you use with your phone, maybe that too... Maybe only your laptops on the main network ?

Comment: Okay, if it's something like a smart tv that you want to control with your phone. But how about a camera, which you access with cellular while away from your house? The phone would not be using any house wifi network so why the requirement to be on the same network? Thanks.

Comment: In that case, it wont even know it is on the guest network. The one issue is that the pairing process may depend on the phone being able to see the camera directly on the network rather than using a registration process that will work without direct access.